# Angular : how to get the loading time of a component after receiving the api response

Tags: angular, components

Angular : how to get the loading time of a component after receiving the api response

Hi Friends,

In my angular application (v13), I need to find the loading time of components after getting the api response. Is there any way to find it.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Do you want to know how long it takes for the component to render itself after the data from the API is received? If that's the case, you can instantiate a `Date` variable in the constructor and then another one in `ngAfterViewInit` and just diff them to see how long the rendering took.

Comment: Hi Octavian, 
Thanks a lot for your response. 
And yes, your understanding is correct on the requirement. I also thought the same way to do like adding a time instance in the ngAfterViewInit and constructor. Whether it is constructor or ngoninit ? Please rectify.

Is there any browser profiling extension, which can give the statistics for this loading time ? Angular profiler I tried, but it is showing the time to load a component; but which is comprised of both api timing and component rendering time right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

You can render the component via Angular's component Renderer, [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#renderer2). Then measure the time passed in the same function.

You can automatize this step for all the components & or maybe you can write them as test cases, but you should provide all the necessary inputs to the component you create.